# To prove FLT, it suffices to prove it for any prime $n \ge 5$.

Tags: number-theory

I once read somewhere, (can't find link) that to prove Fermat's Last Theorem, assuming it has been proven for $n = 3, 4$, it suffices to prove it for every prime $n \ge 5$.  I have no idea why this is true.  Can somebody explain?

Comment: What is FLT????

Comment: $a^{pq}+b^{pq}=(a^q)^p+(b^q)^p$

Comment: @JPi: Fermat's Last Theorem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Suppose $n$ is not prime, then it can be written as $pq$ for some $p,q\in\mathbb{N}$, with $q$ prime, and $a^n$ can be written as $(a^p)^q$ so if there is a solution for $n$ there also is one for $q$ (which is smaller than $n$).

Comment: The OP is asking why it suffices to prove it for *primes* greater than $4$.

Comment: Did you even read the question?

Comment: @ABC: OJB was right, I corrected my answer after because I had initially misread the question

Comment: $a^{p^q} \neq \left(a^p\right)^q$.

Comment: @Eric: Thank you for the correction, I updated the answer

Comment: @OJB The answer was correct, except for the problem with the notation $a^{p^q}$, from the beginning.

Comment: I would point out that you also have to prove FLT for $n=4$ to take care of cases where $n$ is a power of two.